# Как правильно работать с длиной массива?

Tags: c#, массивы, length

К примеру, у меня есть цикл на 1 000 000 итераций, в котором используется массив.

Будет правильнее, если я вынесу длинну массива в отдельную переменную, которая находится за пределами цикла, и после буду обращаться к ней? Или правильнее будет обращаться к свойству массива `Length`?

Какой из способов менее затратный по ресурсу? Когда вычисляется свойство `Length`, при определении массива или при обращение к этому свойству?

Comment: https://www.jacksondunstan.com/articles/3577

Comment: @EvgeniyZ кажется, автор провел неправильные тесты. Я бы прогнал через Benchmark.NET, прежде чем доверять. Вообще при сборке с включенной оптимизацией кода, компилятор обращение к `.Count` по всем канонам должен заинлайнить. А у автора отладочная сборка, да еще и Unity на базе древнего Framework 4.x.

Comment: @aepot Статья 16 года, много что с того времени изменилось, тут да, согласен. Но как пример того, что может быть, если использовать `Count`, думаю вполне актуальна и по сей день, хоть и не для всех случаев)

Comment: А, помню я задавал похожий вопрос про то, не стоит ли проверять `.Any()` у коллекции перед вызовом таски, где эта коллекция будет итерироваться. Ну и типа не делать вызов этой таски, если коллекция пуста. В итоге разница кажется всё-равно оказалась небольшая.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Свойство `T[].Length` вычисляется при создании массива и далее изменено быть не может. Поэтому явное кеширование этого значения в локальную переменную не даст ощутимого прироста к производительности.

А вот при работе с изменяемыми коллекциями, например с `List<T>` кеширование может быть полезным, но не всегда, нужно разбирать частные случаи.

Comment: Я бы добавил к "правильному ответу" информацию от @AlexanderPetrov про оптимизацию. "Следующие поколения" будут на галочку ориентироваться.

Comment: Я тут раздумывал, а может ли Count быть внутренне закеширован? Вполне. Можно ли его поддерживать в актуальном состоянии при каждой вставке или удалении? Да. А стоит ли? Думаю, что Count вызывается не так уж часто, и поэтому оптимизировать его за счёт других операций не стоит.

Comment: К сожалению я могу поставить только одну галочку. Я бы выделил еще и комментарии к ответам, там тоже много интересного.

Answer (score 4):

Предлагаю рассмотреть следующий код:

```
public void M1() {
    var array = new int[10];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        array[i] = 1;
}

public void M2() {
    var array = new int[10];
    
    int len = 10; // array.Length;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        array[i] = 1;
}

public void M3() {
    var array = new int[10];
    
    int len = 20;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        array[i] = 1;
}

public void M4(int len) {
    var array = new int[10];
            
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        array[i] = 1;
}
```

Смотрим машинный код на [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgJgIwFgBQcDMACR2DC2A3utmdqeVrgCzYCySAFAJTGXnkBuYATtn15gAntgC82AHYBTAO7YAlpOABtJAAYAugG4OnCmn3kAZgHt+TJcEXjs67TYA8A3kOEA6ADLTJAc2AAFg4KANQhLHpGZIIiKgqatki6huQAvnp61HB09Ais7ClGPPwxohIy8lZqWslRBnVW2AA2Pon22AD0HS5uXj7+QZHkQ2RmFo0Ktu2Tzi2SwWERhXU9sfGJtWkZy1k5mPkky5zFq2VScorK1Toj9VGNc7YI9re3Y9iWyjYS09izPgtwrdOKU4gkJEk9OllpkcNkGDRPtY5mxDnUTqVbBVLqoNDcjisyG9zB8JlNgn9mgDFItgeRQesIZsyNDUkA=) (вкладка JIT Asm).

Можно увидеть, что в методе `M1` код ассемблера не содержит проверок на выход за пределы массива.

В методе `M2` компилятор достаточно умён, чтобы определить, что значение переменной `len` равно размеру массива (можно задать явно `10`, можно задать `array.Length`) и тоже не вставляет такие проверки.

В методе `M3` значение `len` отличается от константы, используемой при создании массива, поэтому генерируется дополнительный код с проверками.

В методе `M4` аналогично, компилятор не может знать, какое значение придёт извне в параметр `len`, поэтому добавляет кучу проверок.

---

Примечание.
При использовании `ArrayPool<T>` в большинстве случаев не получится использовать свойство `Length`, т. к. размер массива, полученного из пула, будет превышать запрошенный размер. Поэтому придётся указывать размер переменной/константой.

Comment: Вы доказали, что если перед циклом закешировать длину массива в переменной (М2), то это не сломает оптимизацию.

Comment: @rotabor - с локальной переменной это сработает. Но если хранить длину в поле или передавать извне, как в M4, то не работает. А так часто делают.

Comment: Очевидно, что автор спрашивал именно про локальную переменную. Я придерживаюсь мнения, что длину массива можно закешировать в локальной переменной. Вы доказали, что это не сломает оптимизацию. Но почему вы пытаетесь подискутировать со мной по этим случаям: "Но если хранить длину в поле или передавать извне, как в M4, то не работает. А так часто делают"? Вот и обсудите это с теми, кто так часто делает. Или добавьте к вашему ответу, что М3 и М4 делать не нужно, а вот М1 и М2 - это хорошо.

Comment: @rotabor, он доказал, что эта оптимизация не нужна.

Comment: @Qwer откуда такой поразительный вывод? Автор спросил, правильно или нет кешировать длину массива в переменной. Alexander Petrov написал, что это может изменить поведение компилятора при оптимизации, но сам же и показал, что кеширование длины в переменную непосредственно перед циклом не нарушает оптимизацию. Речи о том, нужна ли оптимизация, или не нужна, не было, как и не было показано, что она не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Само собой, все вычисляемые свойства нужно кешировать.
Если производительность является главным критерием, то нужно кешировать всё, что используется более одного раза. Это в равной степени относится и к доступу к члену через ".", и к доступу к элементу коллекции по индексу или ключу.

До входа в цикл сделайте все предварительные вычисления и сохраните значения во временных переменных.

**UPD**

```
using System;
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
    var a = new int[100000000]; // 10E8
    var b = new int[100000000];
    var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; a[i++] = 3);
    Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0); // 0,11
    watch.Reset(); var bl = b.Length; watch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < bl; b[i++] = 5);
    Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0); // 0,11
    }
}
```

Результаты, естественно, получаются разные, но близкие, с переменной время чуть меньше (на несколько миллисекунд) или равное, причём включение или отключение оптимизации на результат не влияет.

Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.8.4084.0
for C# 5

Comment: Нет. Компилятор, видя конструкцию вида `for (int i=0; i<array.Length; i++) array[i] // доступ по индексу` выкинет проверки на выход за пределы массива. А если там будет переменная вместо `array.Length`, то компилятор не сможет этого сделать.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov А к чему, собственно, относится ваш комментарий? К доступу к члену через "."?

Comment: Я про возможность компилятора делать оптимизации. См. мой ответ. / ЗЫ: мерять стопвотчем без "прогрева" кода нет никакого смысла. Только BenchmarkDotNet!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не во всех версиях дотнета компилятор выбрасывает проверки границ. В Framework 4.x может и не выкинуть.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я руками больше десятка раз запускал - грел. В целом замечательно, сколько озвучили нюансов.

Comment: _Я руками больше десятка раз запускал - грел_ - это так не работает...